# How to return values from an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

There is a function that takes an array argument. It is necessary for me that values from objects in lines through a sign "-" would be deduced. Example:
["BMW-55 000-Germany-Hight", "Mitsubishi-93 000-Bar John-3-Japan", "Mercedes-benz-63 000-Germany-Hight"]. Where is the mistake?

```
const car = [
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "country":"Germany",
    "security":"Hight"
  }
 ];


function joinArr(car){
  return Object.values(car).forEach(function(){
     return  car.join("-")      
   });  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array. Use `Object.values` to convert object into an array.

```js
const car = [{"name":"BMW","price":"55 000","country":"Germany","security":"Hight"},{"name":"Mitsubishi","price":"93 000","constructor":"Bar John","door":"3","country":"Japan"},{"name":"Mercedes-benz","price":"63 000","country":"Germany","security":"Hight"}];

function joinArr(car) {
  return car.map(o => Object.values(o).join("-"));
}

var result = joinArr(car);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`car` is not an object, but an array of objects. You might want to map that (and rename `car` to `cars` to avoid confusion):

```
 function joinCars(cars) {
   return cars.map(function(car) {
     return Object.values(car).join("-");
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything - just use `join`:

```
function joinArr(car){
    return Object.values(car).join("-");
}
```

To do this to the full array and get an array of strings, use `map`. Also consider renaming your parameters:

```js
 

const car = [
  {  
"name":"BMW",
"price":"55 000",
"country":"Germany",
"security":"Hight"
  },
  {  
"name":"Mitsubishi",
"price":"93 000", 
"constructor":"Bar John",
"door":"3",
"country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
"name":"Mercedes-benz",
"price":"63 000", 
"country":"Germany",
"security":"Hight"
  }
 ];


const joinArr = cars => cars.map(car => Object.values(car).join("-"));

console.log(joinArr(cars));
```